# compare max value within a range with a specific date using group by

Tags: mysql

I want mysql query to check if the end date's high value is greater than all high within one year range from end date -1 day for that symbol.

MAX with group by and checking it with correct symbol for comparison.  How do I go on with this?

My table structure is:

```
id  Symbol date        high
1   ABC    2015-01-23  45
2   ABC    2015-01-22  40
3   ABC    2014-01-28  33
4   xyz    2015-01-23  37
5   xyz    2015-01-20  70
6   ANO    2015-01-20  170
7   JE     2015-01-25  560
8   JE     2015-01-23  770


SELECT `symbol`,`high` as current_high from history as h 
where date='2015-01-23' 
AND symbol = 'ABC';

SELECT `date`,`symbol`, MAX(`high`) as 1_yrhigh from history 
where date between '2014-01-23' 
and '2015-01-22' AND symbol='ABC'
```

want results if current_high > 1yr_high

So from above sample table's query result should be

```
1 ABC    2015-01-23  45

8 JE    2015-01-23  770
```

xyz is not displayed as `37 < max` ie 70

ANO is not displayed as no record for 2015-01-23 is present

Answer (score 0):

In Order to get current high for each symbol use below query

```
Select symbol,MAX(high) as currentHigh
From table
Where date=CURDATE()
Group By symbol
```

In Order to get last 1 year high except current date use below query

```
Select symbol,MAX(high) as lastOneYrHigh
From table
Where date between (CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY-INTERVAL 1 YEAR)-(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)  
Group By symbol
```

Comment: can i get both result from a single query dude :)